# Is it possible to reconstruct an MSA with PSSM?

Tags: phylogenetics, proteins, phylogeny, pssm

I am thinking of reconstructing an multiple sequence alignment (MSA) of protein sequences from  a position-Specific Scoring Matrices (PSSM).

Is it possible? I suppose co-evolution information is lost in PSSM so maybe it is difficult?

Comment: I edited the question to explain what the acronyms represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short I'm afraid it isn't possible because you lose the linkage per Haplotype which is the core information and vital for any population genetics or phylogenetic analysis.

Position-specific scoring matrix e.g. A .60 C .20 G .20 T 0
I tried to produce a position scoring matrix, but it didn't work out, anyway the allele frequency for each e.g. amino acid are given for each alignment position.

You could produce a consensus sequence which, albeit be hypothetical, it might be of some use to understand the generic behaviour of all the sequences in your sample.

Here's a cartoon describing linkage and its importance,

[image]

For a multiple sequence alignment of course AB and ab are amino acid residues within the same locus. PSSM could be used to construct a matrix to analyses an established alignment, but that's a fairly complicated Phylogenetics calculation (and a separate question).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation from the perspective of linkage!

Comment: You are very welcome @JohnnyTam let me know if you have further questions (posted separately of course as per SE rules).